# Unable to upload client folder to GitHub

Tags: git, github

hope you are doint well !
I'm trying to upload my app to GitHub (Using Node.js and client folder for React).
As I upload the project, I can't enter the 'client' folder. As you can see in the image, there is a strange icon, and the directory isn't clickable as well.
[Screenshot of the main directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmvKV.png).

Thanks in advance for everyone who can help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+arrow+folder

Answer (score 2):

That icon means it's a symlink. The issue is that the React code also has a ".git" folder which makes Github think that this "folder" is another Git project and so, it sym-links it.

To solve your current problem, delete this ".git" folder inside the "client" folder.
The ".git" folder is hidden so use `ls -a` or `ls -Hidden` to view it. Alternatively, use our file explorer provided by our OS.

You can read about [symlinks here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link). Also, I believe this question is already answered on SO.